# How to set css styles with variables in rails if certain item is selected?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm doing the Ryan Bates [Sortable Table Columns](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns?autoplay=true) screencast

If the item is inside a `th` tag and I want to apply a style if the item is selected how can I do it?

Ryan Screen Cast Code:

Controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  def index
    @products = Product.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  end

  # ...

  private

  def sort_column
    Product.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
end
```

Helper

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
  direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => css_class}
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<tr>
  <th><%= sortable "name" %></th>
  <th><%= sortable "price" %></th>
  <th><%= sortable "released_at", "Released" %></th>
</tr>
```

concept

```
<tr>
  <th class=<%= @selected %> ><%= sortable "name" %></th>
  <th class=<%= @selected %> ><%= sortable "price" %></th>
  <th class=<%= @selected %> ><%= sortable "released_at", "Released" %></th>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
.pretty th .current {
  padding-right: 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
}

.pretty th .asc {
  background-image: url(/images/up_arrow.gif);
}

.pretty th .desc {
  background-image: url(/images/down_arrow.gif);
}
```

Comment: have you looked at using datatables? Ryan also has a screencast on this. It may be easier to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what really is the best convention, but I think something like this would work:

```
<tr>
  <%= stylized_th(@selected) { sortable "name" } %>
  <%= stylized_th(@selected) { sortable "price" } %>
  <%= stylized_th(@selected) { sortable "released_at", "Released" } %>
</tr>
```

With an additional helper:

```
def stylized_th(selected, &block)
  content = capture(&block)
  content_tag(:th, content, class: selected)
end
```

You can put some logic in there to determine what class to use based on the value of `selected`. If you want no class, then use `nil`.

I was inspired by this RailsCast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/208-erb-blocks-in-rails-3

I hope it helps.